# meteor conditional html using helpers

Tags: javascript, meteor

newbie question here... I'm trying to get a simple meteor app up but am having trouble getting one of my helper functions called (its seems to be getting ignored).

Basically I wast to use a slightly different html call depending on whether I'm using the first item in a collection or not.

I've added a sequence number to the collection (seq) that starts at 0, created a helper function on the template

```
Template.carousel.helpers({
  sponsors: function() {
    return sponsorDocs.find();
  },
  first_sponsor: function() {
    console.log(this);
    var value = (this.seq === 0);
    if(value) {
      console.log("Got first sponsor");
    }
    else {
      console.log("Not the first sponsor");
    }

    return value;
  }
});
```

and am trying to use it in the template as follows..

```
<template name="carousel">
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="tbCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    {{#each sponsors}}
      {{#if first_sponsor}}
        <li data-target="#tbCarousel" data-slide-to={{seq}} class= "active" ></li> 
      {{else}}
        <li data-target="#tbCarousel" data-slide-to={{seq}} ></li> 
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  </ol>........
```

Now, the each is working fine, but the first_sponsor call never seems to happen (I never see the console log output anyway...

Any idea why? Is there a better way to do this anyway (does seem a bit clunky).

Ta

Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put something visual for each li.  Does 1, 2, or both appear?

Another way to do this is to just have the class name (active or blank) returned by the helper, class="{{sponsor_class}}"
Added:
We may learn that the false path is being taken, and then question why. A common reason is the JavaScript fails. Do you know about your web browsers console?

Comment: Thanks Jim. I can see that the li's are getting populated with the basic data (using the chrome javascript tools), but.. the first_sponsor function doesn't seem to be getting fired at all. I tried your suggestion earlier, but still nothing happened because again I don't think the helper was getting fired.

Comment: There are two paths based on first sponsor. True and false. Which one is being taken? I suspect false; please confirm. Looking at the code, you first log this. I bet that is failing, and showing an exception on your console. This is your problem.

Comment: Close... looking in the console put me onto part of the answer... the answer here is the test needed to be (this.seq == 0) not (this.seq === 0).  But.. now I have another issue.. opened as a new question. By the way.. the console.log of this is fine.

Comment: Great.  So the part in the question that says 'but the first_sponsor call never seems to happen (I never see the console log output anyway...' has been clarified?   Cause that was the baffling part!

Comment: Yes Jim. I think it was probably being called, I was looking in the wrong place for the console output I think.